# Trying to convert a string to an integer

Tags: c

I try to convert a string to an integer by using this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

int StringToInteger(const char* str) {
    int sign = 1, result = 0;
    
    assert(str != NULL);
    
    while (*str == ' ' || *str == '\t' || *str == '\n' ||
           *str == '\r' || *str == '\v' || *str == '\f') {
        str++;
    }

    if (*str == '+') {
        str++;
    } else if (*str == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        str++;
    }

    while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
        if (result > (INT_MAX / 10) || (result == INT_MAX / 10 && *str - '0' > (INT_MAX % 10))) {
            return (sign == 1) ? INT_MAX : INT_MIN;
        }

        result = result * 10 + (*str - '0');
        str++;
    }

    
    return result * sign;
}
```

For some reason, when it gets the following string `5240157683pykjw` it fails. How can I fix this?

For some reason it keeps iterating when encountering a non digit.

Comment: I recommend you start using the `isspace` and `isdigit` functions.

Comment: [Seems fine to me](https://godbolt.org/z/csjEnvjrq). `5240157683` is too large to fit in an int so it returns `INT_MAX`. What do you mean by "it fails"?

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger to see what's going on with the loop and your assorted variables?

Comment: As for your problem, this seems like a perfect time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Oh, and I assume this is a school or book assignment/exercise? Because otherwise you should just use the `strtol` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think an explicit check for a null terminator is necessary, as any increment of `str` only happens when it's pointing to a specific character (e.g. a space, +, -, or digit). For example `StringToInteger("     ")` would return 0.

Comment: Side note, test if your program handles for cases like this: `565a67b7`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The `*str - '0' > (INT_MAX % 10)` check is to specifically handle a string like `2147483648`,  where adding the last digit would made the result greater than `INT_MAX`, but if the last digit was `7` it would be fine

Comment: Another by the way: [The `assert` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) is usually disabled in release code. Please don't use it for run-time checking. Also note that if the assertion fails, the program will *crash*, not exit gracefully or return with an error from the function. Crashing is not very user-friendly.

Comment: Thank you all, it is an exercise from school and I used a special compiler of that school, and it doesn't have the INT MAX and INT MIN functions

Comment: `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are macros (not functions) defined in `<limits.h>`.  If your compiler does not define them, it is irretrievably broken.

Comment: @BarGonen If your environment for some reason didn't have the standard `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` macros, then the code you show would not build, as you use them.

Comment: Note: it may be useful to have your function take a pointer to a `char *` and then set this to the value of `str` _after_ reading all of the digits. You could use this to efficiently read multiple ints from a string.

Comment: Why not `strtod`?

Comment: @BarGonen "For some reason, when it gets this string: 5240157683pykjw it fails. How to fix?" not reproduceable, as in general, code is fine.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: @BarGonen "when it gets this string: 5240157683pykjw it fails." --> I suspect you have a buffer overflow on input in the calling code.

Comment: @BarGonen Minor side issue:  Consider `if (result > (INT_MAX / 10) || (result == INT_MAX / 10 && *str - '0' > (INT_MAX % 10))) {` vs. `if (result >= (INT_MAX / 10) && (result >INT_MAX / 10 || *str - '0' > (INT_MAX % 10))) {`.  The 2nd form may emit faster code.

Comment: @i486 `strtod()` would be a poor substitute for string to integer conversions.  Perhaps you were thinking of `strtol()`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Re "start using the `isspace`".  Maybe.  Typical use of `isspace()` suffers from _signed_ `char` issues and pedantically invokes _locale_ issues.  OP's code is OK.

Comment: If you want access to the `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` macro constants, you must `#include <limits.h>` at the top of the file, because, as already pointed out by someone else, that is the header file in which these macro constants are defined.

Comment: If you want to get really fancy remember there is no requirement that -1*INT_MAX is equal to INT_MIN. Indeed on all modern platforms it is not.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your function. It is not failing on your test string, and it is not continuing to iterate after the last digit. It is correctly returning `INT_MAX` for your input, where you input is an integer greater than `INT_MAX`.